# "Nullifying" the most vectors from mutually unbiased bases

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose I have two orthonormal bases for $\mathbb{C}^d$, denoted $\mathbf{B_1}$ and $\mathbf{B_2}$, such that for any $|e \rangle \in \mathbf{B_1}$ and $|f \rangle \in \mathbf{B_2}$, it is case that $| \langle e| f \rangle| = 1/\sqrt{d}$ (in other words, the bases are *mutually unbiased*).

For a given vector $| \alpha \rangle \in \mathbb{C}^d$, let $Z_{\alpha} = \{ | v \rangle \in \mathbf{B_1} \cup \mathbf{B_2} | \langle v | \alpha \rangle =0 \}$, be the set of vectors from both bases that are orthogonal to $| \alpha \rangle$.

What is the maximum size of $Z_{\alpha}$ for non-zero $| \alpha \rangle$ (i.e. $max_{|\alpha \rangle \in \mathbb{C}^d, |\alpha \rangle \neq 0} |Z_{\alpha}|$)?

In other words, for a suitable choice of the vector $| \alpha \rangle$ (that isn't the zero vector), what is the most number of vectors from the two bases that are simultaneously orthogonal to $| \alpha \rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

This should be (d-1): pick any a vectors from the first basis and any b vectors from the second, where a+b=d-1; they will be linearly independent and hence span a subspace of dimension (d-1) which leaves you with one dimension. When d=2, you can pick at most one vector from one of the bases, for example.

Comment: I thought so too initially, but it doesn't work. For d=4, B1 is the canonical basis and B2={(1,1,1,1), (1,1,-1,-1), (1,-1,1,-1), (1,-1,-1,1)} (normalized). These are MUB with absolute inner product 1/2. Then a=(1,0,0,1) is orthogonal to (0,1,0,0) and (0,0,1,0) from B1 and to (1,-1,1,-1) and (1,1,-1,-1) from B2. When you take the vectors from both bases they might not all be linearly independent. For instance: {(1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), (1,1,1,1), (1,-1,-1,1)} form a 3-dimensional space, not a 4-dimensional one.